# Query with multiple null parameters does not return proper result

Tags: sql

I have a search query where there are 4 parameters. User might provide value of one parameter or more than one parameter. 
4 parameters are

```
FirstName, LastName, ssn, DateofBirth
```

I am using --

```
Select * from person where 
(@FirstName is null or FirstName = @FirstName) Or ((@LastName is null or LastName = @LastName)
or
(@ssn is null or ssn = @ssn) Or ((@DateofBirth is null or DateofBirth = @DateofBirth)
```

In this case if user provide FirstName = "Sam" and LastName ="Paul". I get all the records. I am excepting only the rows which satisfied the condition. Like FirstName = "Sam" LastName = "Gil", First Name ="Mike" LastName = "Paul"

Comment: I think you should go with AND for every parameter rather than OR.

Comment: are the extra opening parenthesis a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `And` between your conditions instead of `Or`:

```
Select * from person where 
(@FirstName is null or FirstName = @FirstName) And (@LastName is null or LastName = @LastName)
And
(@ssn is null or ssn = @ssn) And (@DateofBirth is null or DateofBirth = @DateofBirth)
```

Otherwise whenever any parameter is null, the whole `Or` chain of all conditions is evaluated to true.

---

**Update**: If you want to keep `Or` between the conditions, then try the following:

```
Select * from person where 
(@FirstName is not null And FirstName = @FirstName) Or (@LastName is not null And LastName = @LastName)
Or 
(@ssn is not null And ssn = @ssn) Or (@DateofBirth is not null And DateofBirth = @DateofBirth)
```

(The inner conditions where changed to `And` and `is null` to `is not null`.)

Comment: But AND will return the result for the FirstName = "Sam" AND LastName = "Paul". What if I need all the records where firstname can be "Sam" with any last name and the same way Last Name can be "paul" with any first name?

Comment: +1 but in the second query, all the `is not null` checks are redundant.