# SSRS SubReport background color change

Tags: reporting-services

I need to change the background color of the subreport as per Master reports background color. How can I get the background of any text control in Master report.

Comment: Reena can you please mark accepted answer for previous questions which helped you. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947403/query-with-multiple-null-parameters-does-not-return-proper-result . All volunteers here work hard for those virtual points. I am sure somebody would be able to help you with your new q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the background color through to the subreport as a parameter, use an expression to set the background color to the value of that parameter.  You may find it easier to store the master reports background color in a parameter as well, since it sounds like it too may vary.